# Pass in more information with POST on Flask

Tags: python, rest, flask, post

**UPDATE**: Fixed by passing in

```
<input type="hidden" id="commentID" name="commentID" value={{ comment.id }}>
```

and retrieving the value inside my form with:

```
commentID = request.form.get('commentID')
```

**Original:** I am a complete beginner in Flask, so forgive me if this is a silly question. I am trying to add the functionality to update a comment on Flask.

I'm sure this is a bad practice, but currently, I have a post view which is displayed using the post_id argument you give from url_for(). The forms for both adding a comment and writing a comment are built into the post route itself (pretty sure that's not a good idea.)

```
@posts.route("/post/<int:post_id>", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def post(post_id):
    post = Post.query.get_or_404(post_id)
    postForm = PostComment()
    editForm = PostComment()

    if editForm.validate_on_submit():
        commentID = request.form.get('comment')
        # comment = Comment.query.get_or_404(comment_id) # how do i get the comment id?
        comment.content = form.content.data
        db.session.commit()
        flash("Your comment has been updated successfully.", 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('posts.post', post_id=post.id))

    if postForm.validate_on_submit():
        comment = Comment(user_id=current_user.id, post_id=post_id, content=postForm.content.data)
        db.session.add(comment)
        db.session.commit()
        flash("Your comment has been posted successfully.", 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('posts.post', post_id=post.id))
    return render_template('posts/post.html', title=post.title, post=post, form=postForm, editForm=editForm)
```

I can add comments with this route pretty easily, and I can delete the comments too using another route. However, as mentioned above, I am also trying to add the functionality to update the comment. Currently, I have two forms in the route, one for adding a comment, and another for updating the comment. So, I am trying to get the comment ID somehow from the template, call it using the database, then manually change it. However, I am not too sure how to get the commentID for the database to reference it though.

Here's a snippet of my template:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    {{ editForm.hidden_tag() }}
    <fieldset class="form-group">
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ editForm.content(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ editForm.submit(class="btn btn-outline-info") }}
    </div>
 </form>
```

If anyone could help me solve this, that'd be greatly appreciated. Also, if anyone could let me know a way to improve this practice (maybe a method to create separate routes for adding/editing comments), that'd be greatly appreciated too.

Thanks alot.

Comment: Firstly, you preface your question with you thinking it looks like bad practice several times; it doesn't seem that way to me. What do you want to happen to the old comment? Do you want to maintain a comment history?

Comment: As for now, I just want it to simply update the comment. Maintaining comment history is way too advanced at the moment. And as for bad practice, wouldn't it be better to separate the routes for adding and editing comments instead of having it in the post route?

Comment: To the second part of your question, I'd have to say that I don't compact my routes like this, but I also use a lot of AJAX and found it really clunky with WTForms so I just don't use them

Comment: What do you get after `if editForm.validate_on_submit():` with `print(request.form.to_dict())`?

Comment: Well, validate_on_submit() should work, right? Problem is that I have to get the comment somehow for the route to delete the comment.

Comment: I want to see the form contents

Comment: I edited my first comment, sorry. Please see the original request

Comment: Here is what I get: `content': 'sdsds', 'submit': 'Comment` and a CSRF token

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214620/discussion-between-roganjosh-and-zenalc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you have is that you don't post a row `id` in your form. You stated that your form submits `{content': 'sdsds', 'submit': 'Comment, csrf: ...}` but that's not enough to identify the post.

You didn't show the form itself, but you should add a hidden field with the `post.id`. That way, you can easily overwrite the content.